# Amazon API page number not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, pagination

I'm trying to fetch a list of results for a search through Amazon API to list products on my website. Everything works except for specifying the page number that I want to retrieve. It always fetches page 1 for some reason.

```
$SecretAccessKey = "xxx";
$request['AWSAccessKeyId'] = "xxx";
$request['AssociateTag'] = "xxx";
$request['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
$request['ResponseGroup'] = "ItemAttributes,Offers,Images";
$request['ItemPage'] = 1;
$request['Service'] = 'AWSECommerceService';
$request['Version'] = '2011-08-01';
$request['Operation'] = 'ItemSearch';
$request['SearchIndex'] = $search['category_name'];
$request['Keywords'] = $search['text'];
$request['Page'] = 5;

ksort($request); // Sorts in order of key

$Prepend = "GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\n";
$String = http_build_query($request);
$PrependString = str_replace('+', '%20', $Prepend . $String);

$Signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $PrependString, $SecretAccessKey, True));
$Signature = urlencode($Signature);

$BaseUrl = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?";
$SignedRequest = $BaseUrl . $String . "&Signature=" . $Signature;

// Fetch the generated URL
$xml = simplexml_load_file($SignedRequest);
```

I've tried with `$request['Page']`, `$request['page']`, `$request['Pages']` and `$request['pages']`. None seem to work to pull the correct page. Does anyone know what this parameter is supposed to be named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was `ItemPage`.

```
$request['ItemPage'] = 5;
```

Comment: Indeed, it's documented here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html